# Should I use prices in the following sentence

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns

> The **prices** of books sold online are cheaper than those in the local bookstores.

or

> The **price** of books sold online are cheaper than those in the local bookstores.

Or if both are correct and it's just a style of preference?

Comment: Prices aren't 'cheap', things are. Prices are low or high.

Comment: The prices (plural) of books (plural) are (plural) lower... The price (uncountable) of books (plural) is (singular) lower...

Comment: What has your research told you so far? Have you looked for examples online? Please edit your question to include them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael Harvey correctly points out, prices are lower or higher, not cheaper or dearer.

"Books" can be regarded as several individual things, in which case plural forms are used, as:

> The prices of books sold online are lower than those found in the local bookstores.

Or "books" can be regraded as a general class, in which case singular forms are used:

> - The price of books sold online is lower than that found in the local bookstores.
> - The price of books sold online is lower than the price found in the local bookstores.
> - The price of books sold online is lower than the price found for the same books found in the local bookstores.

In any case, the forms used for one side of the comparison should be the same as those used for the other side.